# нужно преобразовать массив состоящий из массивов, в массив состоящий из объектов

Tags: javascript, функции

```
let tableData = [
  ["firstName", "lastName", "city", "state"],
  ["Elisabeth", "Gardenar", "Toledo", "OH"],
  ["Jamaal", "Du", "Sylvania", "OH"],
  ["Kathlyn", "Lavoie", "Maumee", "OH"],
]
```

нужно преобразовать как-то в

```
 { "firstName" : "Elisabeth", "lastName" : "Gardenar", "city" : "Toledo", "state" : "OH" },
 { "firstName" : "Jamaal", "lastName" : "Du", "city" : "Sylvania", "state" : "OH" },
 { "firstName" : "Kathlyn", "lastName" : "Lavoie", "city" : "Maumee", "state" : "OH" }
```

принцип должен быть на подобии таким

````
let result = tableData.map(([[x1, x2, x3, x4], [y1, y2, y3, y4], [z1, z2, z3, z4], [q1, q2, q3, q4]]) => ([{ x1: y1, x2: y2, x3: y3, x4: y4 }, { x1: z1, x2: z2, x3: z3, x4: z4 }, { x1: q1, x2: q2, x3: q3, x4: q4 },]));```
````

Answer (score 2):

Можно перебрать урезанный на первый элемент (нашу схему) массив (`arr`), каждый элемент этого массива (`val`) с помощью reduce назначить соответствующему ключу (по индексу `i`) аккумулятору `obj`.

```js
const tableData = [
  ["firstName", "lastName", "city", "state"],
  ["Elisabeth", "Gardenar", "Toledo", "OH"],
  ["Jamaal", "Du", "Sylvania", "OH"],
  ["Kathlyn", "Lavoie", "Maumee", "OH"]
];

console.log(createObjects(tableData));

function createObjects(data) {
  return data.slice(1).map(arr => arr.reduce((obj, val, i) => {
    obj[data[0][i]] = val;
    return obj
  }, {}));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const tableData = [
  ["firstName", "lastName", "city", "state"],
  ["Elisabeth", "Gardenar", "Toledo", "OH"],
  ["Jamaal", "Du", "Sylvania", "OH"],
  ["Kathlyn", "Lavoie", "Maumee", "OH"],
];

const newData = [];
for (let i = 1; i < tableData.length; i++) {
  const a = {};
  for (let j = 0; j < tableData[0].length; j++) {
    a[tableData[0][j]] = tableData[i][j];
  }
  newData.push(a);
}
console.log(newData);
```